# Is it possible to follow progress of particular package managers?

Tags: package-management, packaging

I notice that my node.js on the latest Ubuntu is only 0.4.12, but I'm trying to install something that needs 0.6.

Is there a way to see the team who are involved in packaging this? Or track progress?

Update : Thanks for the answer to my specific node.js issue, it's very useful. BUT I really wanted to ask the question that I asked - is there a way to follow the people doing the packaging for Ubuntu and to track their progress?  (The node.js was just an example of why I might want to do this.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each package has a corresponding page on launchpad:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nodejs

Here you'll see the versions of node in each version of Ubuntu it is shipped in, and at the bottom a list of other (potentially untrusted) sources of node that other people might be packaging it.

As far at the maintainer goes, if you click on a specific version page:

- https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nodejs/0.4.12-3ubuntu2

You'll see that the maintainer is listed as "Ubuntu Developers", with James Page being the last one who touched it. For questions about that package it's best to probably post on [this mailing list](https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/ubuntu-devel-discuss).

Answer (score 1):

a quick google of 'node.js ppa' showed [this ppa](https://launchpad.net/~chris-lea/+archive/node.js/?field.series_filter=oneiric) which currently has version 0.6.12 (the latest).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
```

Then update your system.

Comment: Although this answer is technically correct, the format is bad. Google may misguide you. Using official sources: http://nodejs.org/#download -> https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager -> the PPA mentioned by you (ppa:chris-lea/node.js)